# Scroll by different amounts in Zathura

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pdf-viewer

I would like to be able to scroll by different amounts, using the keyboard, in Zathura.  In `zathurarc`, you can set the amount by which you scroll:

```
set scroll-step 40
```

Is there a way to change this amount and bind it to a shortcut?  E.g., make  a shortcut for setting scroll-step to 400, moving down, and setting it back to 40?

I know about the `feedkeys` function (e.g., `map <C-p> feedkeys ":print<Return>"`), but it does not take multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
map <F2> feedkeys ":set scroll-step 400<Return>"
map <F3> feedkeys ":set scroll-step 40<Return>"
```

This sets F2 to scroll-stop 400 and F3 to the default.

Comment: Do you know if this works for all versions of Zathura? I have `zathura 0.5.2
girara 0.3.7 (runtime: 0.3.7)` and this is not quite working for me.

Comment: I was using zathura 0.4.9 which used girara 0.3.7 (runtime: 0.3.7)

Comment: Mind taking a look at this [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736939/how-to-make-a-zathura-keybinding-to-execute-two-commands?noredirect=1#comment1399469_736939).